# Anyone has had Youtube Data Api Giving Quota Exceeded when it didn't?

Tags: youtube-data-api, quota

In the last 2 days (Nov/5 and 6) I'm getting **Youtube data API Quota Exceeded** msg, but my api dashboard shows the number of queries below the allowed quota (this is a non-paid account).
Has anyone experienced the same problem recently?

Comment: yes, same issue.

Comment: the problems seems to have gone away. Probably an Youtube fluke.